# Get class name at class level

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the name of a class at class level in Python?

Minimum working example:

```
class TestClass:

    print("We are now in the class {} at class level".format(WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?))  # Should return "We are now in the class TestClass at class level"
    pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can find out:

```
class TestClass:
    print(locals())
```

This prints:

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'TestClass'}
```

So you can use `__qualname__`, i.e.

```
class TestClass:
    print("We are now in the class {} at class level".format(__qualname__))
```

Answer (score 0):

**For defined classes only:** Use `type(self).__name__` where `.__name__` is a default attribute.

Refer to [@Alex Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149554/8080186) for using the class name before `__init__` takes place, using `locals()`.

Comment: @Adriaan is asking how to do it before the `__init__`, so `self` is not useable

Comment: My bad, updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
class Test :
   CLASSNAME = locals()['__qualname__']
```

Use the CLASSNAME variable anywhere in the class or outside.

Comment: You can just use `__qualname__` directly.